# Pytorch audio map time point to location in spectrogram

Tags: python, audio, pytorch

I have an audio file that lasts 294 seconds (sampling rate is 50000). I use torchaudio to compute its spectrogram the following way:

```
T.MelSpectrogram(sample_rate=50000, n_fft=1024, hop_length=512)
```

Say, there is an important event in the original .wav audio at second 57 exactly. How can I determine exactly what pixel that event will start at on the spectrogram.

Or, put simply, how can I map a moment in an audio to a location in a spectrogram?

Comment: What you want is impossible from the point of view of basic physics and mathematics.  A single moment does not have a spectrum - a spectrum can only be computed from a time-dependent series.  This is sometimes called the "Fourier uncertainty principle", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform.  The math here is sophisticated but perhaps it would help to note that frequency has units of waves per second, and you're asking what is the frequency at a single instant (i.e., zero seconds).  That implies division by zero so it's an undefined quantity.

Comment: If you look at a spectrogram and you detect a phonem, a noise, or something characteristic, can you know at what moment in time that sound was uttered? That is what I want to know. I'm not asking the frequency of a moment in time or anything like that.

Comment: By the way, aren't spectrograms a plot of frequencies vs time? I've seen spectrograms with seconds on the x-axis. How do they map waveform time to spectrogram time?

Comment: You can get the spectrum of a short segment of the waveform, and if it contains an interesting feature then you can identify an approximate time for that event.  In other words, you can slice the waveform into little pieces and make some statement about the frequencies contained in each piece.  You can never localize to single point in time, but you can approach it.  The shorter you make the pieces in time, the less resolution your spectrum will have.

Comment: A spectrogram is a plot of amplitude versus frequency.  A stream of sound is amplitude versus time.  They are mathematically related, but a spectrogram with "time" on the X-axis makes no sense to me.  Could it have been "inverse time", time to the minus -1 power?  That's how physicists often write frequency, which has units of one over time.

Comment: I could not quickly find a good online reference for the math, but maybe this will help: https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/Nyquist-Theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram#/media/File:Spectrogram-19thC.png afaik this is frequency vs time

Comment: Yes, but if you look carefully you will see that the frequency data consists of bands that extend a short distance along the X axis.  This kind of data can be generated as I described: you chop the time series into short slices and measure a spectrum for each slice.  You can then look for features in those spectra but with a limited time resolution.  For auditory signals I think you could probably get decent information with time slices of about 0.02-0.05 seconds, but I'm not an expert in that exact problem.  I am familiar with the math because of my background in optics and lasers.

Comment: 0.05 is an acceptable error band for my problem. In theory, I guess I could take a small slice from the waveform data when the event happens, turn it into a spectrogram, and try to match it with the full spectrogram to see the pixel location of that fragment. Would that work?

Comment: No.  There is no such concept as "the pixel location of that fragment."  The spectrogram always depends on the WHOLE fragment.  For example, suppose you get the spectrogram of a fragment.  Now change one point in the waveform: ALL the points in the spectrogram will change, depending on the magnitude of the change you made.  The math here is called Fourier analysis; I don't know a quick and dirty explanation.  The spectrogram shows the frequencies that are present in the entire waveform or fragment.  A frequency is a periodic cycling of amplitude, so can't be localized to an instant in time.

Comment: Ok, so what's on the x-axis of a mel spectrogram. If y is frequency and color is amplitude, what is x exactly?

Comment: I created a chat room to continue with this discussion: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/249149/spectragram-discussion.  I've never done this before and I hope I did right!